# Connect four game- making a grid

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a connect four game. At this point, I am trying to make the game for console interaction only and am having trouble making the grid to look like this format:

Create 7 columns and each containing '.' till the time replaced by either color(just in case the formatting is not shown correctly):

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  Y  .  .  .  .
.  Y  R  .  .  .  .
.  R  Y  .  .  .  .
.  R  R  .  .  .  .
```

here is what I have so far:

```
NONE = ' '
RED = 'R'
YELLOW = 'Y'

BOARD_COLUMNS = 7
BOARD_ROWS = 6

# board=two dimensional list of strings and
# turn=which player makes next move'''    
ConnectFourGameState = collections.namedtuple('ConnectFourGameState',
                                              ['board', 'turn'])

def new_game_state():
    '''
    Returns a ConnectFourGameState representing a brand new game
    in which no moves have been made yet.
    '''
    return ConnectFourGameState(board=_new_game_board(), turn=RED)

def _new_game_board():
    '''
    Creates a new game board.  Initially, a game board has the size
    BOARD_COLUMNS x BOARD_ROWS and is comprised only of strings with the
    value NONE
    '''
    board = []

    for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
        board.append([])
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            board[-1].append(NONE)

    return board
```

Comment: What is your question?  What results are you getting now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set `NONE` to `'.'`, not a space. Then, you could make such a print function for the board:

```
def printBoard (b):
    print('  '.join(map(lambda x: str(x + 1), range(BOARD_COLUMNS))))
    for y in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        print('  '.join(b[x][y] for x in range(BOARD_COLUMNS)))
```

Used like this:

```
>>> x = _new_game_board()
>>> printBoard(x)
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

And when reconstructing your example state:

```
>>> x[1][-1] = RED
>>> x[1][-2] = RED
>>> x[1][-3] = YELLOW
>>> x[2][-1] = RED
>>> x[2][-2] = YELLOW
>>> x[2][-3] = RED
>>> x[2][-4] = YELLOW
>>> printBoard(x)
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  Y  .  .  .  .
.  Y  R  .  .  .  .
.  R  Y  .  .  .  .
.  R  R  .  .  .  .
```

If you are interested, I made a simple implementation of the whole game based on this idea. You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/poke/6934842).

Comment: Thanks poke..but I am supposed to usethe following code and build upon it:

Comment: No worries, I just got interested in building it on my own yesterday, and since I got it working, I thought why not share it? :)