# python connect 4 board output error

Tags: python, output

I want to print a connect four board to the console, I have the following code:

```
def print_Board (b):
print('.'.join(map(lambda x: str(x + 1), range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS))))
for y in range(connectfour.BOARD_ROWS):
    print('. '.join(b[x][y] for x in range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS)))
```

The output should look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
R . . . . . .
R Y R . . . .
Y Y R . . . .
```

but its coming out as:

```
1.2.3.4.5.6.7
. . . . . . 
. . . . . . 
. . . . . . 
R . . . . . 
R Y R . . . 
Y Y R . . .
```

Comment: What is the content of `b`?

Comment: here is the reference to the whole code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307340/connect-four-game-making-a-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If empty cell is represented as empty string or space character, you can dump it as follow.

```
def print_board (b):
    print(' '.join(map(lambda x: str(x + 1), range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS))))
    for y in range(connectfour.BOARD_ROWS):
        print(' '.join(b[x][y].strip() or '.' for x in range(connectfour.BOARD_COLUMNS)))
```

---

```
>>> print_board([
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'R', 'R', 'Y'],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Y', 'Y'],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'R', 'R'],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
...     [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
... ])
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
R . . . . . .
R Y R . . . .
Y Y R . . . .
```

Comment: Here is the link to the whole code, maybe this helps      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307340/connect-four-game-making-a-grid